# css float issue: block is being 'pushed' down?

Tags: css, image, layout

I'm making a simple layout as part of a web site. It has multiple blocks, each with similar content. Here's the html/css:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            .content {
                width: 900px;
                display: block;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 10px;
                background: #fea;
                margin: 20px;
            }
            h2, p {
                display: block;
                width: 580px;
            }
            img {
                background: white;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 270px;
                height: 330px;
            }
            h2, p, img {
                display:block;
                float: left;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='content'>
            <img class='auto' src='img/test.jpg' alt='test image' />
            <h2>Title one</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
                sed do eiusmod tempor <em>incididunt</em> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. 
            </p>
            <p>
                ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
                esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
                sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class='content'>
            <h2>Title two</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. 
            </p>
            <p>
                ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
                esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                Excepteur sint occaecat <a href='#'>cupidatat non proident</a>, 
                sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <img class='auto' src='img/test.jpg' alt='test image' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The second image is displayed lower than expected. What causes this, and is there a way to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the img tag in the second div above the p elements.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your html...

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style> 

.content {
width: 900px;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 10px;
background: #fea;
margin: 20px;
}
h2, p {
 display: block;
 width: 580px;
 }
  img {
   background: white;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 270px;
   height: 330px;
     }
 h2, p, img {
 display:block;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class='content'>

<img class='auto' src='img/test.jpg' alt='test image' />

<h2>Title one</h2>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor <em>incididunt</em> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. 
</p>

<p>
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>

  </div>


  <div class='content'>
 <img class='auto' src='img/test.jpg' alt='test image' />
 <h2>Title two</h2>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. 
</p>

 <p>
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
    Excepteur sint occaecat <a href='#'>cupidatat non proident</a>, 
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>



 </div>

 </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS to `float` your text and images:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<style>  

.left {
float:left;
}

.right {
float:right;
}

.content { 
  width: 900px; 
  display: block; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding: 10px; 
  background: #fea; 
  margin: 20px; 
} 
h2, p { 
  display: block; 
  width: 580px; 
} 
img { 
  background: white; 
  padding: 5px; 
  width: 270px; 
  height: 330px; 
} 
h2, p, img { 
  display:block; 
  float: left; 
  margin-left: 10px; 
  margin-right: 10px; 
} 

</style> 
</head> 
<body> 

<div class='content'> 

    <div class="left">
    <img class='auto' src='img/test.jpg' alt='test image' /> 
    </div>

    <div class="right">
    <h2>Title one</h2> 

    <p> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,  
        sed do eiusmod tempor <em>incididunt</em> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.  
    </p> 

    <p> 
        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit  
        esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.  
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,  
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
</p>
</div> 

</div> 


<div class='content'> 

    <div class="right">
    <img class='auto' src='img/test.jpg' alt='test image' />
    </div>

    <div class="left">
    <h2>Title two</h2> 

    <p> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,  
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.  
    </p> 

    <p> 
        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit  
        esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.  
        Excepteur sint occaecat <a href='#'>cupidatat non proident</a>,  
        sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
    </p> 
 </div>

</div> 

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the second image before `<h2>` inside `<div class="content">` with following style:

```
<div class='content'>
 <img class='auto' src='img/test.jpg' alt='test image' style="float:right;"/>
 <h2>Title two</h2>

 <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. 
 </p>

 <p>
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
    Excepteur sint occaecat <a href='#'>cupidatat non proident</a>, 
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Or you can use css class to achieve the same:
Check the `to_right` and `to_left` css classes in below code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
     .content {
       width: 900px;
       display: block;
       overflow: hidden;
       padding: 10px;
       background: #fea;
       margin: 20px;
     }
     h2, p {
       display: block;
       width: 580px;
     }
     img {
       background: white;
       padding: 5px;
       width: 270px;
       height: 330px;
     }
     .to_right{float:right;}
     .to_left {float:left;}

     h2, p, img {
       display:block;  
       margin-left: 10px;
       margin-right: 10px;
     }

     </style>
     </head>
     <body>

     <div class='content'>

         <img src='img/test.jpg' alt='test image' class="auto to_left"/>

         <h2>Title one</h2>

         <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
             sed do eiusmod tempor <em>incididunt</em> ut labore et dolore magna                        aliqua. 
             Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. 
         </p>

         <p>
             ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
             Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
             esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
         Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
         sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </p>

     </div>


     <div class='content'>
        <img src='img/test.jpg' alt='test image' class="auto to_right"/>
         <h2>Title two</h2>

         <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
             sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
             Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. 
         </p>

         <p>
             ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
             Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
             esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
             Excepteur sint occaecat <a href='#'>cupidatat non proident</a>, 
             sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         </p>

     </div>
     </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image as well the paragraphs and the `h2` are defined with `float: left`.
As both `p` and `h2` have a fixed width, you can't put two of these into one line (580px*2 > 900px), so they wrap.

However, an image will fit next to a paragraph (or a title), so it will be displayed at the same height.

To display the image right tothe title, you'll have to swap your floating style for the image to "float: right" and place the image before the `h2` tag.

You can find a (cleaned-up) fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xmujr/

I removed most of the float directives, as they aren't needed for anything except the image. I also added a class (left / right) to the image to make clear where the image will be shown.

HTH